# how to count the true false answer and show the Score card in the last in textview

Tags: android, textview, boolean, concatenation, counting

private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressed) {

```
    boolean answerProvided = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isQuestionTrueAnswer();

    int yourScore=0;

    int messageStringId = 0;

    if (answerProvided == userPressed) {

        messageStringId = R.string.correct_toast;

        yourScore += 1;

    }

    else {

        messageStringId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
```

yourScore -= 1;

```
    }

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, messageStringId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);

```
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Does nothing yet, but soon!

           checkAnswer(true);

           mTrueButton.setEnabled(false);

           mFalseButton.setEnabled(false);

           mMoreInfoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    });
```

mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);

```
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Does nothing yet, but soon!

          checkAnswer(false);

            mFalseButton.setEnabled(false);

            mTrueButton.setEnabled(false);

            mMoreInfoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    });
```

I have 20 questions and for each correct answer I want to add +1 in yourScore variable and for every incorrect answer subtract 1 in yourScore variable. And at the end of 20 questions I want to show the score in textview but unable to do it. please help me and thanks in advance. how to show the value of yourScore variable in textview?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textView.setText("your final score is:" + yourScore);`. Replace `textView` with the name of the textview you want to use.

Comment: how to return the value of yourScore variable for every question as i have created private void method

Comment: I am getting  1 score for each right answer and -1 for each wrong answer, but because I am not able to return the value to the yourScore variable that's why for every answer it is starting with yourScore = 0, and giving a score either +1 or -1. i  want the sum of these values. so, in the end i can show as a total score. but not able to return because of void method. what to do